# Get rows with common column values in output

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark 1.6 dataframe (3 columns) with records in following format -

```
----------
w  p  s
----------
w1 p1 0
w1 p1 1
w1 p1 2
w1 p2 0
w1 p2 1
w2 p1 0
w2 p1 1
w2 p3 0
w2 p3 1
w2 p3 2
w2 p4 0
w1 p4 1
w3 p1 0
w3 p1 1
w3 p2 0
w3 p3 0
w3 p4 0
w4 p1 0
w4 p1 1
```

// **Updated output as per updated input**
Next I want to transform it to get rows that have same values in column 2 and 3 like below, eliminating all the records uncommon to w -

```
----------
w  p  s
----------
w1 p1 0
w1 p1 1
w2 p1 0
w2 p1 1
w3 p1 0
w3 p1 1
w4 p1 0
w4 p1 1
```

I tried using self-join but I get all the records as in input dataframe, another way I could think of is to get a distinct combination of w and p and join it with input dataframe, then get distinct combination of p and s and join it with input dataframe.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to achieve the required output.

//**Updates - using self join** 
I used following self join query -

```
df.registerTempTable("t")

sqlContext.sql("select distinct t1.w,t1.p,t1.s FROM t AS t1 JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.p = t2.p  and t1.s = t2.s  where t1.w != t2.w")
```

which resulted in following output, p2,p3,p4 do not overlap across all w so they should not be in output -

```
w1 p1 0
w1 p1 1
w2 p1 0
w2 p1 1
w3 p1 0
w3 p1 1
w4 p1 0
w4 p1 1
w1 p2 0
w2 p3 0
w2 p4 0
w3 p2 0
w3 p3 0
w3 p4 0
```

// **Updates using window function**, I havent used window functions much so I tried this simple queries, but I am not sure how can I get desired results, I am close but not sure what is missing -

```
val df1 = sqlContext.sql("select  w,p,s, row_number() over ( order by p,s) as rn, rank() over ( order by p,s) as rk, dense_rank() over ( order by p,s) as dr from t")

val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select  w,p,s, row_number() over (partition by p order by p,s) as rn, rank() over (partition by p order by p,s) as rk, dense_rank() over (partition by p order by p,s) as dr from t")
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would appreciate if I know the reason for downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer doesn't need a join**. Comments are provided for clarity

```
//should know the distinct w to check for the output
val distinctListOfW = df.select("w").distinct().collect.map(row => row.getAs[String](0))

//selecting p ans s of any random w (first here) to check of p and s repetion across all w collected above
val firstW = distinctListOfW(0)
val p_and_s_of_first_w = df.filter($"w" === firstW).select("p", "s").collect().map(row => (row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[String](1)))

//creating empty dataframe for merging sebsequent dataframes which matches the logic
val emptyDF = Seq(("temp", "temp", "temp")).toDF("w", "p", "s")

//fold left on the p and s collected of any random w and if the condition of count of distinct w matches with p and s then merge else return the previous df
val finaldf = p_and_s_of_first_w.foldLeft(emptyDF){(tempdf, ps) => {
  val filtered = df.filter($"p" === ps._1 && $"s" === ps._2)
  val tempdistinctListOfW = filtered.select("w").distinct().collect.map(row => row.getAs[String](0))

  if(filtered.count() > 0 && (tempdistinctListOfW.length == distinctListOfW.length)){
    tempdf.union(filtered)
  }
  else{
    tempdf
  }
}}.filter($"w" =!= "temp")

// this is the final required result
finaldf.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+
|w  |p  |s  |
+---+---+---+
|w1 |p1 |0  |
|w2 |p1 |0  |
|w3 |p1 |0  |
|w4 |p1 |0  |
|w1 |p1 |1  |
|w2 |p1 |1  |
|w3 |p1 |1  |
|w4 |p1 |1  |
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple SELF-JOIN like this should work?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.as("df1").select(col("w").alias("w1"), col("p"), col("s"))
    .join(df.as("df2").select(col("w").alias("w2"), col("p"), col("s")), ["p","s"])
    .filter(col("w1") != col("w2"))
```

Comment: I tried self join, I am not syntactically aware of pyspark but your query seems equivalent to sqlContext.sql("select distinct t1.w,t1.p,t1.r FROM t AS t1 JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.p = t2.p  and t1.r = t2.r  where t1.w != t2.w")
this doesn't eliminate records that are partially occurring across few rows ...updating my question to reflect the scenario

Comment: maybe your `"and"` is not working? try another syntax like mine. Do you work with Pyspark or the scala API ?